# How to answer Spivak chapter 5 question 2.4?

Tags: calculus, limits

I have been working through Spivak and not able to solve this question for hours and hours. So the question says :

> Find $\delta$  such that  $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$ for all $x$ satisfying $0<|x-a|<\delta$
>   given $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+\sin^2(x)},a=0,l=0$.

Now I've gone through this question by a lot of ways.
I took the basic approach. No Lemmas.

Let $x < A$ where $A$ is any positive integer. So $1+\sin^2(x)$ is the controlling factor here. To control the growth of $x$ , $1+\sin^2(x)$
must be greater than $x$. But $1+\sin^2(x)$ can't be greater than 2 hence the value of $x$ must be  less than then 0. I feel like I've strayed quite away form the approach to solve this. any help or guidance will be appreciated.

The answer is $\delta= \varepsilon^2$.
How??????

Answer (score 0):

The notation is pretty cumbersome as *specific* values of $\;a,\,l\;$ are given, so rephrasing: find $\;\delta>0\;$ s.t. $|f(x)|<\epsilon\;$ whenever $\;0<|x|<\delta\;$, for $\;f(x)=\cfrac x{1+\sin^2x}\;$, so we need in fact to prove

$$\lim_{x\to0} f(x)=f(0)=0$$

Take an arbitrary $\;\epsilon>0\;$ , so we need to prove the existence of $\;\delta>0\;$ as above. Observe though that $\;\sin x\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}0\;$ , so we can *choose* $\;\delta>0\;$ so that

$$\;|x|<\delta\implies|\sin x|<\frac1{10}\implies-\frac1{10}<\sin x<\frac1{10}\implies 0.9<1+\sin x<1.1\implies$$

$$|1+\sin x|>0.9$$

$$|f(x)-0|=|f(x)|=\frac{|x|}{|1+\sin x|}<\frac{|x|}{0.9}=\frac{10}9|x|\stackrel{\text{we want!}}{\color{red}<}\epsilon$$

Well, complete now the exercise and find a delta such that if $\;|x|<\delta\;$ ...etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking in a too complicated way.

One simply notice that
$$
0\le\frac{|x|}{1+\sin^2 x}\le |x|
$$
So one can take $\delta=\varepsilon$ to get the desired proof.

---

Notes.

The edition of Spivak's Calculus does *not* have the indicated problem in Chapter 5, though there are similar ones. The "answer" $\delta=\varepsilon^2$ appears for the function $\sqrt{|x|}$. You must be looking at the wrong thing.

[image]

[image]